run script for multiple selected objects
I have this script which I want to run on all selected objects so that I don't need to select each object and run the script again and again. The script separates the selected object by vertex groups. What do I need to change?
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene

for ob in scene.objects:
    
    def main():
        origin_name = bpy.context.active_object.name
        keys = bpy.context.object.vertex_groups.keys()
        real_keys = []
        for gr in keys:
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
            # Set the vertex group as active
            bpy.ops.object.vertex_group_set_active(group=gr)

            # Deselect all verts and select only current VG
            bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
            bpy.ops.object.vertex_group_select()
            # bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='INVERT')
            try:
                bpy.ops.mesh.separate(type="SELECTED")
                real_keys.append(gr)
            except:
                pass
        for i in range(1, len(real_keys) + 1):
            bpy.data.objects['{}.{:03d}'.format(origin_name, i)].name = '{}.{}'.format(
                origin_name, real_keys[i - 1])


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
        
#Switch back to object mode
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```


You have placed the main function into a loop. That's strange and doesn't work. It just freezes Blender. Also, the last "switch back to object mode" should be in the main()/loop because there you switch to Edit mode at the beginning. If you fix this and remove the outer loop (for ob in scene.objects), the script will run fine for the active object.

To make the script run for all selected objects you have to do "the stuff" in a loop. I would rename main() to seperate_mesh_by_vertex_groups() and call this function in a new main function, in a loop for the selected objects. The challenge is that the “bpy.ops.xxxxx” operators require the object they are working with to be in context. You therefore need to work with overwritten contexts. I'll have a closer look at this later.
